# How to remove an Angular library created with CLI (ng generate library)

Tags: angular, angular-cli

To create a library in angular6 we use the following:

```
ng generate library my-lib
```

If we wish to remove the previously created library, what is the the command:

Answer (score 56, accepted):

All you have to do is following steps :

1. Delete the folder `projects/my-lib`.
2. Go to the `angular.json` file and remove the `"my-lib"` object section contained in `"projects"`.
3. Go to `tsconfig.json` and remove `"my-lib"` object section from `paths`.

Comment: Also remove the relevant path in tsconfig.json paths object.

Comment: would be nice to have that thing automated though

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/19691

Comment: Create a feature request above.

Comment: There is already a schematic for that @nrwl/workspace:remove

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Nx workspace 9.1.3 you can achieve that with [remove](https://nx.dev/react/plugins/workspace/schematics/remove) workspace schematics plugin e.g. `nx g @nrwl/workspace:remove <project-name>`

Answer (score 1):

Delete the content/lib inside project/libs and look for the affected files, angular.json,
package.json, nx.json(if using nx workspace), tsconfig.json and delete the respective library path entries.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with even shorter command:

```
nx g rm <library_name>
```

For instance:

```
nx g rm my-lib
```